# How to upload mp4 video in wysiwyg editor in magento

Tags: file-upload, tinymce, magento-1.9, wysiwyg

```
<adminhtml>
 <cms>
    <browser>
        <extensions>
            <allowed>
                <mp4>1</mp4>
            </allowed>
        </extensions>
    </browser>
 </cms>
</adminhtml>
```

after I add this to my config.xml 
I upload an mp4 file, but a warning of unsupported format of image shows up.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, I recommend creating a local module to avoid to modify core files. Then, override the following Magento classes:

- Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image
- Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Images_Storage

Changing the validate function comparing with the video/mp4 filetype: mime_content_type($filePath) == 'video/mp4'

Adds the mp4 extension to the array of allowed and image_allowed from your config.xml located on your module folder, ex: Mycompany/Mymodule/etc/config.xml

```
<adminhtml>       
        <cms>
            <browser>
                <extensions>
                    <allowed>
                        <mp4>1</mp4>
                    </allowed>
                    <image_allowed>
                        <mp4>1</mp4>
                    </image_allowed>
                </extensions>
            </browser>
        </cms>
</adminhtml>
```

After deploying the module on your Magento folder and clearing your cache, you should be able to upload mp4 videos through WYSIWYG editor.

Then, you can include videos on the CMS Pages like this:

```
 <video width="1280" height="960" controls="controls">
       <source src="{{media url="path_of_the_video.mp4"}}" type="video/mp4" /> 
    </video>
```

I made an example that you can use as a reference:
https://github.com/fontelag/mag_videos_upload